# How to change the colour of materials from already created 3D model

Tags: texturing, materials, color

I'm new to Blender and I bought a 3D wine bottle model and have tweaked it to fit what I need. The file came with its own textures. Diffuse, specular, glossy, and so on. I have imported them to match the different materials in my file. [image]

I however need to make a Rose bottle as well which is essentially a clear coloured glass with the pink liquid inside. I suppose it doesn't really matter if I just make the glass pink but I'm not sure how to make it look good without just making the glass a bright unrealistic pink.[image]

I'm not sure if using a color ramp is supposed to be the way to do it or if I should be changing something else. The model that I bought looks like this from the website.

[image]

I had to convert the file to an obj as the fbx file had the version 6100 could not be supported error pop up when I tried to open the orginial file so not sure if I was supposed to look like this from the very start and the converting to obj made me have to restart the coloring.

I have my glass material nodes here. [image]

My liquid material nodes here. [image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: Hello so what does it give if you change the colors of the ColorRamp to pink?